# Counting number of sub-groups in Access reports

Tags: ms-access, report

If I have a report with the following groupings:

```
Group1
  Group2
    Group3
      Details (records)
```

How do I count the number of Group3's that appear in each Group1.

All I can get is the number of records in each group, or the total number of each group.  I can't get the total number of subgroups per group.  Please help me.  Thanks guys!

less general example:

```
Facility1
  patient1
    exam1
      schedule attempt1
      schedule attempt2
    exam2
      schedule attempt3
      schedule attempt4
      schedule attempt5
  patient2
    exam3
      schedule attempt6
      schedule attempt7
Facility2
  patient3
    exam4
      schedule attempt8
      schedule attempt9
```

Question is, how many exams at each facility?  Would like that to appear in facility group header.

For facility1, for example, I either get 7 (num sched attmpts) or I get 4 (num total exams on report).  Correct answer is 3.

For facility2, for example, I either get 2 (num sched attmpts) or I get 4 (num total exams on report).  Correct answer is 1.

Data is from results of a query:

```
facility1 - patient1 - exam1 - schedatt1
facility1 - patient1 - exam1 - schedatt2
facility1 - patient1 - exam2 - schedatt3
    .
    .
    .
facility2 - patient3 - exam4 - schedatt8
facility2 - patient3 - exam4 - schedatt9
```

Comment: Is this all stored in 1 table or is this joined together from multiple tables?

Comment: This is query results from 3 tables in a cascading one-to-many relationship.